# Launch a service or action on getting FCM notification in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a basic chat app using flutter and firebase. I am using FCM to receive the message. Now, if I receive a message while the app is in the background, I want to add it to my local SQLite database. However, onResume and onLaunched are only called when the user clicks on the notification. So is there a way to launch a custom action directly on flutter or will I need to write native code for both platforms as described here: https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

I am using Notification messages btw as data messages are pretty much useless in flutter when it comes to background work.